# jquery Scroll automaticly, play videos, restart

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, html5-video, autoscroll

I have a single webpage that will have text and videos embedded using [javascript video](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_av_dom.asp). What javascript/jquery code can I use to scroll down the page by a set speed, stop scroling, play a video, and then continue scroling until the bottom of the page where it restarts?

Edit:
I have tried http://www.jquerybyexample.net/2013/05/jquery-scroll-page-automatically-by-few-pixels-after-every-few-seconds.html and http://jdsharp.us/jQuery/plugins/AutoScroll/ and http://jsfiddle.net/NaP8D/11/.

```
//run instantly and then goes after (setTimeout interval)

$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, 4000);
setTimeout(function() {
   $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:0}, 4000); 
},4000);
setInterval(function(){
     // 4000 - it will take 4 secound in total from the top of the page to the bottom
$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, 4000);
setTimeout(function() {
   $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:0}, 4000); 
},4000);

},8000);
```

I have not been able to get the code to pause on any of them.

Comment: Edited post and added what I've tried.

Comment: Nowhere in your code does it wait for the video to play/ wait till the video stops playing. Is that what you're having issues with?

Comment: That code was from the jsfiddle. But yes, that code works, pausing the scrolling and making it wait is the problem.

Comment: Ok, give me a few minutes to whip some code up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should give you a rough idea of what you need. Without some HTML code or more JS, I can't give a specific answer. Here, `#myVideo` is the `id` of the video.

```
// scrolls to the video
$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $("#myVideo").offset().top }, 4000);

// $("#myVideo") should return a video element
var video = $("#myVideo");

// called when the video/playlist ends
video.onended = function() {
     // scrolls to the bottom of the page
     $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, 4000);
};
```

You're going to have to modify it slightly to match your code. If you want to loop it:

```
while(1){
  $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $("#myVideo").offset().top }, 4000);
  var video = $("#myVideo");
  video.onended = function() {
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, 4000);
    setTimeout(function() {
        $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(0).height() }, 4000);
    },4000);
  };
}
```

Comment: What does the "4000" do in the code? What would it control if it was changed?

Comment: How long it takes to scroll down to the video.

Comment: Also, what would need to be added in order to refresh everything, i.e create an infinitely running page?

Comment: Is 4000 = 4 seconds?

Comment: Yes, 4 seconds. And there are a few ways to do that, the stupidest being putting everything in a while(1) loop. I'll add that to my answer.

Comment: Thanks! Made a small change to the looping code, i added a timeout.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99635/discussion-between-chase-cromwell-and-arcanecraeda).

Comment: To play the video after scrolling to it, would you add `video.play();` to the line after the first line?

Comment: Yeah, you would place it after `var video = $("#myVideo");`

Comment: I've been trying out this code, it seems to be scrolling weirdly. When you get a chance, go to that chat link.